# Change of variables to go from $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$ to $u_{\epsilon n}=0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-learning, change-of-variable

Consider the following PDE $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$, $c=1.$ Notice that with the following change of variables $$x=\epsilon+n \\t=\epsilon-n\\\implies \epsilon=\frac{(x+t)}2,n=\frac{(x-t)}2$$ we get $u_{\epsilon n}=0$.

**Exercise** Use an analogous change of variables to go from $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$ to $u_{\epsilon n}=0$.

My attempt:

I've thinking about consider $x=\frac{(\epsilon+n)}{2}$ and $t=\frac{(\epsilon-n)}{2}$. This implies: $\epsilon=x+t$ and $n=x-t$.

Will this change of variables work?

Is there an easier  change of variables to work with? please tell me!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. The example and the exercise share the same PDE?

Comment: Shouldn't the first example be just $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$? Without $c$ in the change of variables, you won't get $u_{\epsilon n}$ otherwise.

Comment: oops sorry there is a typo, yes you're right @HansLundmark

Comment: @CheeHan mmh there was something missing: c=1 , my mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, try $x = c(\epsilon + n)$ and $t = \epsilon - n$. This is an exercise of chain rule. For instance, 
\begin{align*}
u_\epsilon & = u_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial\epsilon} + u_t\frac{\partial t}{\partial\epsilon} \\
& = cu_x + u_t. 
\end{align*}
I shall let you finish the computation.

Comment: Thank you Chee Han, I'll do the computations